# Disable landscape mode for a whole application

Tags: java, android, screen-orientation

Is the there a way to set a landscape mode to the whole application, not by adding `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` to every activity in AndroidManifest?

Comment: That's not how you're supposed to handle this sort of thing in Android.  Unless you have a very good reason for doing so, I would recommend doing this in the manifest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's the only thing I can think of.  Write a class that extends Activity and put the following in that class:

```
setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Then, instead of extending Activity in your other classes, extend the new class.

Comment: Where do you put this, in the oncreate method?

Comment: Yes - you can put it in the onCreate method of the super class.  Just don't forget to call super.onCreate from your extended class.

Answer (score 7):

One programmatic way of doing this, that I can think of, is to create a super class that extends activity and extend all your classes from there.

Have the below setting in the super class in a protected method and call super.xxx() to initiate this:

```
setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

In case you what a specific activity in a different way you can simply override this.

[I have not tried this yet, but by the knowledge of OOP this works]

Comment: sometimes when an activity is started using this method it can quickly  jump from landscape to portrait so I would advise against this!

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting that attribute in the  node of your manifest. I don't know if that is supported though. And if not Im afraid putting it in each of your  is going to be the next easiest way.

You might be able to achieve it by making yourself a CustomActivity that extends activity and sets the window flags to be Portrait in the onCreate. Then with all of your other activities you could extend your CustomActivity instead of plain Activity.